# python sklearn - clustering visited web pages

Tags: python, url, matrix, cluster-analysis, scikit-learn

I have a large database (arround 2 millions entries) of the form:

```
userId         url
54    :      myjournal.eng/politic/technology_in_city
32    :      myjournal.eng/life/food
45    :      myjournal.eng/science/labs
78    :      myjournal.eng/politic/tea_party
86    :      myjournal.eng/music/concert
54    :      myjournal.eng/technology/glasses
```

and I want to cluster using python sklearn in order to get a few groups of users and try to determine links between topics (for instance, users who likes food also like sport.. or such kind of links).

My approach is: I parse the url and get for each id a group of stemmed word (for instance, user 54 would get ['techno','glas','politc','techno','cit']), then I transform this list of documents into a TfIdf Matrix, using TfIdf vectorizer, then I use a Kmeans.

My question is: is it a good idea to use a TfIdf Matrix since It can lower the importance of the categorys (politic, music, technology etc..), and so make a clustering less reliable. And is Kmeans a good idea for clustering such data (very sparse matrix with lot of columns)? I can't lower the number of feaures since the matrix is sparse, so the sklearn algo won't work.

Comment: Really I think you won't know for sure until you try, it sounds like this is more suited to collaborative filtering, where you classify similar users based on their tastes (like Amazon recommending you products other people who bought the same item as you), in which case tf-idf would not be a good choice IMO but this depends on how your data is distributed.

Comment: I would suggest looking at Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) for topic modelling for your problem. Take a look at the [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) project.

Comment: Hi, First thank you for you comments. I tried a Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI) which is the ancester of the LDA, but I am not sure I understand the results. More specifically, how should I interpet the topics (or concepts). I see in some topics, politics and sport have more importance for example, but I can't imagine what a topic is really.

Comment: I don't think clustering is the right approach to use. Topic modeling is probably much more helpful, or frequent itemset mining.